# Add xy Data from csv adds data but changes xy values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, coordinates, csv

I have an issue with adding xy data from csv. files.
Data in csv properly formatted `(name, x-point,y-point,z-point)`.

After importing them, when I click on Identify it shows location x and y coordinates that differ from the ones I tried to import.

Hopefully this picture will show what i am trying to say:

[image]
Any leads?

Ok. I open arcmap, set coordinate system, click on "Add xy data", point to csv file, select fields that contain x y and z coordinates, load it. Then I go to export data to shp file. Once the ship file is loaded, I click on one of the points to display xyz values. X and y are different then the values in csv file, z is ok

Comment: Do not let "unknown units" mislead you. It is the same when I select feet

Comment: Your question text does not mention unknown units. What were the detailed steps that you performed to see that result? Also, include a picture of the first row from your CSV.

Comment: What coordinate system is your dataframe? Have you defined that same coordinate system for the feature class that you imported?

Comment: I am not at work right now, so I can not include any attachments. Data frame is in PR State Plane. Same happens with coordinate system defined and when it is not defined (tried several combinations). Csv file has header row (name, point_x, point_y, point_z).

Comment: Rather than describe superficially the combinations that you have tried it will be much more helpful to just see the details of one workflow that you expected to see work when it appears not to have.

Comment: The offsets look like a datum (GeoCRS) difference. Is the data and data frame both using the same GeoCRS like NAD83 HARN or Puerto Rico?